# Jmeter - Sharing CSV file data between 2 thread groups out of 3 thread groups

Tags: apache, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have **3 thread groups** in my **test plan** and a **CSV data set config** element and I want to share CSV Data with two thread groups out of 3, I went through jMeter documentation and they have mentioned like,

Sharing mode:

> **Identifier** - all threads sharing the same identifier share the same
>   file. So for example if you have 4 thread groups, you could use a
>   common **id** for two or more of the groups to share the file between
>   them. Or you could use the thread number to share the file between the
>   same thread numbers in different thread groups.

But here I am not getting how and where to set the **id** like identifier in thread group...

Answer (score 1):

In the Sharing Mode, you need to mention the function `${__threadNum}` which is nothing but the **Identifier**.

For more details, refer [How to use CSV Config Set's sharing mode to run thread in Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292760/how-to-use-csv-config-sets-sharing-mode-to-run-thread-in-jmeter)