# How to use CSV Config Set's sharing mode to run thread in Jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter

Is there any way to use this option "edit" of "share mode" in CSV Data Set Config? I have found the description in official web site?

[apache jmeter component CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

> Identifier - all threads sharing the same identifier share the same
>   file. So for example if you have 4 thread groups, you could use a
>   common id for two or more of the groups to share the file between
>   them. Or you could use the thread number to share the file between the
>   same thread numbers in different thread groups.

But I don't understand what is the mean of common id and thread number? How can I use them for the particular thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example you have `file.csv` with the following content:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

And 2 [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 2 users and 1 Loop executing a Sampler with the following label:

```
Sampler ${__threadNum} - ${foo}
```

For different Sharing Mode settings you will get the different behavior i.e.:

- For sharing mode `All Threads`:

  ```
  Sampler 1 - line1
  Sampler 1 - line2
  Sampler 2 - line3
  Sampler 2 - line4
  ```
- For sharing mode `Current Thread Group` you will get:

  ```
  Sampler 1 - line1
  Sampler 1 - line1
  Sampler 2 - line2
  Sampler 2 - line2
  ```
- For sharing mode `Current Thread` you will get:

  ```
  Sampler 1 - line1
  Sampler 1 - line1
  Sampler 2 - line1
  Sampler 2 - line1
  ```
- For sharing mode `${__threadNum}` you will get:

  ```
  Sampler 1 - line1
  Sampler 1 - line2
  Sampler 2 - line1
  Sampler 2 - line2
  ```

Example [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan):

[image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config ThreadNum]

References:

- [__threadNum() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)
- [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)