# CSV dataset config in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using CSV data set config for parameterization purpose in jmeter but I want the setting to be done as below:
The total number of threads are 20. There are 40 values in my CSV. I want all my threads to take first value during their first iteration and second value during second iteration. But JMeter is assigning unique value to all 20 users in the first iteration itself. Please help me how can I do this?

Comment: Please refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292760/how-to-use-csv-config-sets-sharing-mode-to-run-thread-in-jmeter

Comment: Solved... Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your requirement you need 20 threads to

1. Read lines from 1 to 20 during first iteration
2. Real lines from 21 to 40 during second iteration

In order to achieve this:

1. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   [image]
2. Add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of the associated request and configure it like:

   [image]
3. That's it, this way you will get confidence that all 20 users will execute first 20 calls before proceeding to the next iteration:

   [image]